# How to login on Android app

Tags: support, android-app

I have an account using my G+ google account. I just installed Stack Exchange app on my android phone and it doesn't give me an option to use my G+ to sign in, what should I do to get to the same account on my phone?

Thanks.

Comment: android 6.0 right? (if not, it's not a dupe)

Comment: It was 6.0 and I found the post that had asked the same question, thanks. I hope someone is working on fixing that bug; Android 6.0 and runtime permissions require some extra care from the app.

Comment: Don't get your hopes too high, there's only one single developer working on the android app, and he's most likely busy with other bugs and improvements.